# What are the minimal pom dependencies of Xpand?

Tags: xpand

I use Xpand for code generation inside a maven plugin project. So, I need to add the required libraries as dependencies in `pom.xml` in order to define and use Xpand templates. What is the minimum list of dependencies that should be added to the pom?

Answer (score 1):

you may take the following as starting point

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xpand</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xpand</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.xpand</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xpand</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecore</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-v200706262000</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>20040117.000000</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>55.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Added these dependencies and got error messages complaining that `org.eclipse.jface` and `org.eclipse.jface.text` are missing. What are they used for? Why should they be necessary?

Comment: hmmm maybe you need some additional dependencies. i ran it via rightclick run only